# get first letters from each word in a string with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Have a powersshell to return a list of folders from DFS, I want to reduce long folder names to their resultant acronym. This is what I have so far, it replaces space with underscores...

```
$folders = Get-DfsnFolder -Path "\\dfs\path\*"| %{$folder = $_.path.split("\"); $folder[4].replace(" ","_")}
foreach ($folder in $folders) { if ($folder.length -gt 24) {

if ($_.length -gt 20) { $_.split("?<=\_)[\_]+").substring(0,1); 
   <Do something here to put the letters back into $folders>
    }
}
```

Essentially I want an acronym creator

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand why you want the underscores, is that a separate requirement for strings shorter than 20 characters?

Anyway, for splitting a string in to words and returning only the first letter of each word, you can combine split and join like this:

```
("this is a test" -split " " |% { $_[0] }) -join ""
```

Combined with your code, you can use something like:

```
$folders |% { 
  if($_.length -gt 20) {
    ( $_ -split " " |% { $_[0] } ) -join "" 
  } else {
    $_.replace(" ","_")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Rename-Item` cmdlet:

Rename-Item takes a [destination path] and a [source path]

```
Rename-Item $_.FullName $_.Name.Replace(' ','_') -Force #this is for the space to underscore `Replace`

Rename-Item $_.FullName $_.Name.Substring(0,1) -Force #this is for the first letter `Substring`
```